# Can we set textbox field type in C# like in HTML?

Tags: c#

I am a web developer and I am creating some small WindowsFormApp in Visual Studio Express

What I want Is this: Allow only numbers in my text field like in HTML.

```
<input type="number">
```

Is it possible to do this in C# like in HTML to set the textbox to accept only numbers or I need to make this function?

```
// if input is empty warn user
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Amount field is empty!");
}
else
{
    int numberOfLabels = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: is this webforms?

Comment: no...WindowsFormApp

Comment: You cannot, but you can use `Int32.TryParse()` on your text to cancel events for input when it's `false`. Or use a basic regex like `\d`.

Comment: WinForms does not provide this functionality for the TextBox control. However you can use the NumericUpDown control (and this will work also if your user uses the clipboard to paste text)

Comment: OK, i have made that code and I have a button which is dependable on that textbox, and if the textbox is empty then it tries to work with it and I get an error....

Comment: That could be avoided using Int32.TryParse checking the result

Comment: I'll try it...but the answer to my question is already given....we can't set the textbox type like in HTML!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a handler for the [KeyPress event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx). If the key does not correspond to a digit, then set the `Handled` property of the [KeyPressEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`, which will prevent the Textbox from registering the keystroke.

Edit:

As [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) pointed out, a user could enter the text via clipboard. In that case you can use the [TextChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) as well. Every time you accept the changed text, store it in a variable. When you want to reject text, use the `TextChanged` event to restore to the previous accepted value.

Comment: And what if you paste text in the control?

Comment: I want to know this also

Comment: @Stveve -- Well, there's always the [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event as well.

Comment: But if you can use the NumericUpDown control, what is the point in doing all this work?

Comment: @Steve -- Of course, I realize that this might be an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but we don't know what the actual constraints are. Maybe the customer just really, really wants a TextBox, and lewis4u will look a lot better if he can deliver that exact solution.